# Cast exception when using IncludeFilter with EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

So, I'm facing some problems when trying to run an IncludeFilter query. My project is built upon .NET 4.5.2 and I'm using EF6.

What I need is to be able to filter the results because using the standard Include method would just return a huge amount of data.

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
{"Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[SQL.Repository.ContractServices,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SQL.Repository.ContractServicesInstallments]]]' to type 'SQL.Repository.ContractServices'."}
```

My code is the following:

```
public async Task<List<ContractServices>> GetAll(FilterDTO filterDTO, long companyID)
{
            
var listContracts = await context.ContractServices
                .IncludeFilter(a => a.ContractServicesInstallments.Where(b => b.DueDate 
                               >= DateTime.Today))
                .Where(a => a.companyID == companyID)
                .Skip(filterDTO.Skip)
                .Take(filterDTO.Take.Value)
                .ToListAsync();
                return listContracts;
}
```

If I run this with the standard .Include, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
public async Task<List<ContractServices>> GetAll(FilterDTO filterDTO, long companyID)
    {
                
    var listContracts = await context.ContractServices
                    .IncludeFilter(a => a.ContractServicesInstallments.Where(b => b.DueDate 
                                   >= DateTime.Today))
                    .IncludeFilter(a => a.ContractServicesInstallments.Where(a => a.companyID == companyID))
                    .Skip(filterDTO.Skip)
                    .Take(filterDTO.Take.Value)
                    .ToListAsync();
    
                    return listContracts;
    }`enter code here`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doens't work. The ```companyID``` attribute belongs to ContractServices and not to ContractServicesInstallments and that's why I'm using it on a Where outside of the IncludeFilter, since I need to get only the ContractServices from a specific ```companyID```.